# How do I integrate Google plus login in my ionic app (v3)

Tags: ionic3, cordova-plugins

I did this following stuff below:

```
import { QuestionPage } from '../question/question';
import { GooglePlus } from '@ionic-native/google-plus';

    g_login(){
    if(this.platform.is('ios')){
      this.googlePlus.login({})
      .then(res => console.log(res))
      .catch(err => console.error(err));
    }else{
      this.googlePlus.login({
        'webClientId': '********-i5v3qk3dj7*********j6s7vr.apps.googleusercontent.com'
      })
      .then(res => console.log(res))
      .catch(err => console.error(err));
    }

  }
```

And I got this following error:

> Error code 12500